# SQL SERVER WHERE CON FORMAT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo una consulta necesito en sql server mostrar solo mes y año y sobre este dato realizar un where, ya he podido mostrar solo mes y año pero no me realiza ninguna accion al momento de poner el where, me pueden comentar si tengo que agregar FORMAT al where o como puedo ejecutarlo. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No,no debes agregar ningún `FORMAT` al `WHERE`  (que solo es para visualizar). En el `WHERE` busca por fecha.

Comment: No uses imagenes a menos que sea realmente necesario.. tu codigo debe i como texto...